# Scraping com R - xpathSApply retornando uma lista de 0

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping, scraping

Estou aprendendo a leitura de dados em XML em R.

Queria extrair as informações do futebol brasileiro (nome do campeonato, mandante do jogo, resultado, etc.) deste site: https://www.terra.com.br/esportes/equipes/sao-paulo/lista-de-jogos com o pacote XML.
Meu código ficou o seguinte:

```
[1] fileUrl <- 'http://www.terra.com.br/esportes/equipes/sao-paulo/lista-de-jogos'
[2] doc <- htmlTreeParse(fileUrl, useInternalNodes = T)
[3] championship <- xpathSApply(doc,"//h3[@class='header-matches']", xmlValue)
```

Porém, a função xpathSApply acaba me retornando uma lista de 0. Alguém sabe o porquê?

Testei o código no site do Globo Esporte e tive sucesso, imagino que tenha a ver com o código XML em si do site do Terra.

Comment: Eu dei um parse na resposta e vi que tá tudo em javascript, salvo engano. Você não vai conseguir via xpath. Tenta usar regex: `httr::GET(url) %>% httr::content("text")`  %>% stringr::str_extract_all(....).